# Why is alcohol not permitted, if it requires the will of Allah to make you drunk?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, alcohol

I understand that as Muslims, you believe that absolutely nothing happens without the will of Allah.  For example, if you take painkiller, it will only work if Allah wills it.

What I don't understand is that as Muslims, you've been warned by Allah to not drink alcohol, because you go out of control.  That's true and that is fair.

What I don't understand is that, that alcohol will only make you drunk if Allah wills it to make you drunk.  So why warn, people not to drink it, and then will the alcohol to make them drunk?

Why not allow people to drink alcohol and will the alcohol to not make them drunk?

For example, why warn people that if they drink alcohol, it's benefits are not worth the side effects, when the alcohol will only make you drunk when god wills it to make you drunk?

Comment: God leaves your choices to you-- doesn't temper with them and that's the beauty of it. waiting for someone to answer to comment on, this is a lengthy answer. Your first line narrowing it all down the wrong way.

Comment: you should learn God's will first, before say about God's will

Comment: The same for why shouldn't kill people, or commit any sins.

Answer (score 1):

God has made rules that govern the physical universe. Laws of physics are manifestation of God's will. Similarly He has made human and the way that he designed it, alcohol will mess up his normal thinking.
Since, as humans, our most differentiating factor is that we can think and reason, anything that hampers it, is warned.
A fire will burn, although He can tell it, not to. This world is made as a test, so there will be things that will be harmful and we will be tested to keep away from them.

Comment: Do you have any authentic Islamic texts about God creating rules which govern the physical universe?

Comment: Quran mentions in http://quran.com/21/33 about heavenly bodies "swimming" in orbits, which we now defined in Law of gravity and Kepler's laws (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion)

Answer (score 1):

That Allah guarantees that the world *works*, that is when you light a fire it burns, that when you drink water it slakes your thirst was fully thought out & explicated by the Ash'arite Theologian Al-Ghazali - he called it Occasionalism.

Allah guarantees the laws of this world, and does not change them. We understand them as the laws of nature. For Allah to make alcohol not intoxicating means firstly that He will have to break that guarantee - and He does not break his own Word; and secondly if alcohol did not make people intoxicated it could no longer, in all truth be considered as alcohol.

The question is why are intoxicants forbidden: Firstly one can make errors of judgement whilst intoxicated; secondly because it can become an addiction and finally because in extreme cases it is a poison.

As you point out during their time in this material world, muslims are warned off drinking alcohol, because there is both good & bad to wine, but the bad is greater than the good - that is it is not intrinsically & wholly bad - as pointed out in Surat [Al-Baqarah 2:219](http://quran.com/2/219) (The Cow):

> They ask thee concerning wine and gambling. Say: "In them is great sin, and some profit, for men; but the sin is greater than the profit." They ask thee how much they are to spend; Say: "What is beyond your needs." Thus doth Allah Make clear to you His Signs.

But after leaving this life - it is not forbidden, but encouraged. But notice the Wine here is mixed with Kafur, or Pure & Holy.

[Surat Al-'Insān 76:5](http://quran.com/76/5) (The Man)

> As to the Righteous, they shall drink of a Cup (of Wine) mixed with Kafur,

[Surat Al-'Insān 76:21](http://quran.com/76/21) (The Man)

> Upon them will be green Garments of fine silk and heavy brocade, and they will be adorned with Bracelets of silver; and their Lord will give to them to drink of a Wine Pure and Holy.

Comment: Do you have any authentic Islamic text where God gives this guarantee of the laws of this world?

Comment: Tahāfut al-Falāsifa (The incoherence of philosophers) by Al-Ghazali.

Comment: So just to sum up, are you saying that Allah has set everything in motion by setting many physical laws in this world such as the laws of physics, and he will not interfere with these laws?  So with the law of alcohol, a person will get drunk, and it is not a real-time will of allah, but a will of allah because it's a law set by allah that the effect of alcohol will make you lose control?  Is that basically what you're saying?

Comment: I'm not saying that. Al-Ghazali says that Occasionalism isn't about just creating the laws & setting everything in motion but also keeping everything in motion too. Paraphrasing Al-Ghazalis example of this is putting cotton wool in a candle flame will not burn unless Allah wills it. In other words he guarantees/wills cause & effect. It is in real-time. The effect of alcohol is not *only* to make people lose control, it evaporates, it's used as a solvent amongst others.

Comment: So you're saying that Allah has to will each and every effect of a cause in real-time (so to speak), otherwise everything will fall apart?, and the laws always work because of Allahs guarantee, and they will always work because Allah has guaranteed to will the laws to work every single time because Allah will not break his guarantee?

Comment: @user3550: Yes. But please remember that this is Al-Ghazalis argument not *mine*. By the way, that there is a problem with cause & effect had been noted by the British Philosopher Hume in the 18C. He didn't offer a solution.

Comment: Sounds a bit dodgy to be honest.  Kind of implies that we have the ability to control God, i.e. if I get a piece of metal which is untreated, and leave it out exposed to all the elements, it is guaranteed to rust, based on the laws of nature which ensures that metal will rust if left untreated exposed to all the elements.  So based on Al-Ghazalis argument, we humans can create causes (i.e. leave metal out to rust), which Allah has to effect (must make it rust) because he guaranteed it, and he can't break his guarantee...  This doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Thats an interesting twist. It raises question about what is a cause & what is meant by free-will & what is the nature of a guarantee.  Al-Ghazali is a major Islamic Philosopher so it wouldn't surprise me if he's already tackled your objection in his book somewhere. I haven't - I just have some acquaintence with the idea. But one way to begin answering your objection - is to ask how did you put that iron outside in the rain? Your hand is a physical object, the nerve impulses that go from your brain to your hand are electrochemical and so are physical.

Comment: When you picked up the iron, it was Allah that  *allowed* you to do that or *guaranteed* that this was possible.

Comment: So basically, free will accordng to islam means the freedom to think and make decisions.  We have no control over anything else, i.e. taking action after a decision is not possible without Allah's will?

Answer (score 0):

God knows what will happen, 
but doesn't make it happen for you. 
If you're drinking, you're doing 
so to get what you expect out of it. 
If drinking out of an addiction 
against your will, 
then got to make your mind to stop it and God helps you. 
Helps your mood, see the right way to go about it, ... .

Alcohol isn't strictly forbidden BTW. There are cases the physician approves and is alright in those cases. From what I know, unhealthy 
food is forbidden in Islam to the degree it is so.

Please also read my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Every aspect of physical and non-physical laws have been created by Allah and hence that is how our existence is possible. He has enabled these laws to operate within an environment that he has also created. Space and time are fabrics of this environment. As a consequence free will exists within Islam.

Allah doesn't intercede into every cause and effect situation, and this is not why Muslims mention the term "if Allah wills". Muslims are acknowledging the omnipotent and all-knowing characteristic of Allah as the creator of all that is known and unknown, to existence and what might seem as non-existence to us... It is our humbleness and piety to our limited understanding of Allah. Of course, we are not able to understand Allah more than the realm of our human understanding. Admitting this limitation reduces human arrogance into seeking understanding of the extra-existential, but instead on the knowledge within the boundaries of human existence.

Comment: Furthermore, cause and effect can be argued as a probable relationship in the social world (philosophically speaking).

Answer (score -2):

Allah is trying to make some easy doing for us and make some of them as warning to us not to reach, he can stop us automatically not to have the upportunity to do the wrong things but he really wanna see who will not do the wrongs just for the word of Allah only and  it by forcing.

Answer (score -5):

It's nothing to do with Allah.

If alcohol is forbidden because of its effect on humans brains, why it wasn't forbidden at christian ages. did Allah find out bad effects after Jesus?!

It's all about economy and politics.

In very first years of Islam, business of making wine was in hand of enemies. and also the arabs couldn't control him self on drinking. so wine beamed forbidden.